# Downloading pretrained Efficient Det in google colab with TensorFlow Object Detection Api gives a series of unknown warnings?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I have created a notebook that downloads pretrained model from tf2 detection model zoo and performs prediction using saved model . The notebook is working fine on other models such as centernet, faster rcnn etc. But whenever I download efficient det using the download function below it issues a series of warnings.

MY DOWNLOAD FUNCTION

```
def download_model(model_name):
  
   
  download_url = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/'
  
  
  pretrained_model = model_name
  
  
  model_file = pretrained_model + '.tar.gz'

  
  
      
  !wget {download_url + model_file}
  tar = tarfile.open(model_file)
  tar.extractall()
  tar.close

    
  model_dir= os.getcwd() + '/' + pretrained_model        # determine the path to saved model 
  model_dir=pathlib.Path(model_dir)/'saved_model'
  model= tf.saved_model.load(str(model_dir))

  return model
```

The warnings I encounter:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
```

Eventhough my Efficient Det Model runs ok, I don't understand why is this warning being issued and how to get rid of it. I am making a notebook tutorial for others to understand TFOD but these warnings make my notebook look messy. Is there anyway I can suppress these warnings?

Answer (score 0):

I think this was resolved in `tf-nightly`, there i can see few `WARNING:absl:Importing a function`. Your issue can be resolved in future stable `TF 2.5`.

Please refer working code as shown below

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2' 
import tensorflow as tf

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

import os
import tarfile
import pathlib


def download_model(model_name):
  
   
  download_url = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/'
  
  
  pretrained_model = model_name
  
  
  model_file = pretrained_model + '.tar.gz'

  
  
      
  !wget {download_url + model_file}
  tar = tarfile.open(model_file)
  tar.extractall()
  tar.close

    
  model_dir= os.getcwd() + '/' + pretrained_model        # determine the path to saved model 
  model_dir=pathlib.Path(model_dir)/'saved_model'
  model= tf.saved_model.load(str(model_dir))

  return model

model_name= 'efficientdet_d1_coco17_tpu-32'
model= download_model(model_name)
```

Output:

```
2.5.0-dev20210225
--2021-02-25 14:25:20--  http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/efficientdet_d1_coco17_tpu-32.tar.gz
Resolving download.tensorflow.org (download.tensorflow.org)... 74.125.142.128, 2607:f8b0:400e:c08::80
Connecting to download.tensorflow.org (download.tensorflow.org)|74.125.142.128|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 51839363 (49M) [application/x-tar]
Saving to: ‘efficientdet_d1_coco17_tpu-32.tar.gz.1’

efficientdet_d1_coc 100%[===================>]  49.44M   219MB/s    in 0.2s    

2021-02-25 14:25:20 (219 MB/s) - ‘efficientdet_d1_coco17_tpu-32.tar.gz.1’ saved [51839363/51839363]

WARNING:absl:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_119744) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:absl:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_132687) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:absl:Importing a function (__inference___call___37213) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:absl:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_124597) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:absl:Importing a function (__inference_EfficientDet-D1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_137540) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:absl:Importing a function (__inference_bifpn_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_95809) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:absl:Importing a function (__inference_bifpn_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_97913) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
```